# Word recognition with MSP430

Tags: speech-recognition, voice

In my DSP class at my university I have to create a simple word recognition system using the MSP430. Basically the board just needs to turn on and off an led at the commands "On" and "Off". My question is more along the lines of finding a good tutorial which I can learn the general steps to perform this. I am learning about MFCCs, would this be a good starting point?

Thanks,
Micah

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  Your question is a little off-topic for here. Could you think about rewording it and making it more specific?  For example, tag it with `reference-request` and ask about MFCCs.  Otherwise I expect people will want to close this as-is.

Comment: Hmm, well my question is general in nature. I am asking about a general method for word recognition. I am not sure how else to ask it.

Comment: Try searching for more questions here (like [this](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15529/good-methods-for-hardware-based-1-2-word-speaker-independent-speech-recognition)  or [this](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17897/using-hmm-for-speech-recognition) or [these](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/search?q=word+recognition) and then formulate a more specific question.